# Calculated width sometimes lacks some pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I've got a script that should calculate the width of the element:

```
function CalculateWidth(content, style) {
    var mySpanSize = 0;

    try {
        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        span.innerHTML = content;
        span.style.cssText = style;

        document.body.appendChild(span);
        mySpanSize = span.offsetWidth;
        document.body.removeChild(span);
    } catch (err) {
        return 0;
    }

    return mySpanSize;
}
```

The `content` is HTML formated text, e.g:

```
<font size="2">Some text here.<br/>Some another text. Another text</font>
```

And the `style` is css string, e.g:

```
border: 1px solid black; 
margin-top: 8px; padding: 
5px; text-align: left;
```

The function works.. somehow... but the calculated width sometimes lacks from 20 to 50 pixels to make the width of destined container fit the `content`.

How to fix that (except some kind of hackish `+50` at return ;))

I can't use jquery or any other JS lib.

---

@EDIT [2015-08-13]

Example `content` (that's all passed in single line):

```
<font size="2">XX: XXXXX<br>XXXX XXXX: XXXXXXX<br>XXXXXXXX: XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX (XX-XXX XXXXXX, XXXXXX (XX. XX.XXX/XX) )<br>XXXXXX: XX XXXXXXXX<br>XXXXXXXX XX: XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX</font>
```

Sorry for `X`'s. If such example is not enough I'll try to fix up something better.

Example `style`:

```
border: 1px solid black;
margin-top: 8px;
background: #F5F5F5;
padding: 5px;
text-align: left;
```

Comment: With the br in the middle that's the correct size.

Comment: There's no chance I can modify the content. I can only outsmart the 'user' with that JS function (and maybe helpers, but no outside libs). Is there no other way?

Comment: Notice, that `<font>` has been deprecated for years ago, it should not be used anymore. Your issue might partially due to the `font` and its `size` attribute?

Comment: It might be, but as I said **I cant modify** the `content` at all, and the `content` 99% of times comes with `<font>`.

Comment: Basicly you've invalid HTML, and it's not guranteed browsers will show its content or calculate its dimensions correctly. In your function you can remove the `font` tags _before appending_ the content to the body, and set the size the font in style part. At least worth of trying.

Comment: If you can't modify the content, be on your guard for HTML injection. Anyway, I put the material in your question in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/50x322qL/1/), and it results in the precise width of the resulting span being output. No 50 pixel mismatch! So can you link to something that does demonstrate the issue? Or, preferably, edit your question and create a snippet.

Comment: The `content` in my question was just an example to give slight idea (although the `<font>` and `<br>` tags are real). I cant really post the real `content` coz it's the company data. I'll try to fix something up tomorrow when I get back to work. Also we're working on IE only (please dont ask).

Comment: @user2475983 That's OK, I needed to create a website that had to be IE6 compatible as recently as 2012.